# Treating a single object like an array with one element, taking one-past-end pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

**Preamble:**  It is well-known that taking the pointer one past the end of an array is legal and well-defined:

```
int main()
{
  int na [1] = {};
  const int* naBegin = na;
  const int* naEnd = na + 1; // one-past-end, OK  
}
```

This pointer can be used in comparisons, which contributes to C-style arrays (or, more accurately, pointers therein) being compatible with Standard Library routines which take iterators, such as `copy` ([Live Demo](http://ideone.com/hWqxmV)):

```
template <typename Field, typename Iter>
void foo(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  std::copy (begin, end, std::ostream_iterator <Field> (std::cout, std::endl);
}
int main()
{
  int na [1] = {};
  foo <int> (na, na + 1);
}
```

The legality and definedness of this is supported by the Standard (C++03 reference):

### 5.7 Additive operators

> 5/When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
>   i–n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, **the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object.** If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

When I've looked in the Standard for references to the vlaidity of past-the-end pointers, every reference I've found is discussing arrays.  What if we were to try to take past-the-end the address of an object, not an array?

---

**Question:**  Is it possible to treat a single object, *not allocated as an array*, as if it were an array and take a valid one-past-the-end address of said object?

For instance ([Live Demo](http://ideone.com/FxBsuq)):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Field, typename Iter>
void foo(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  std::copy (begin, end, std::ostream_iterator <Field> (std::cout, "\n"));
}
int main()
{
  int na = 42;
  foo <int> (&na, &na + 1);
}
```

Is this code legal and well-defined by the Standard?

Comment: /4 "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Comment: @dyp that was exactly the line I was going to quote

Comment: Although the answer to this question was trivially easy to find, I'm not going to delete the question as it could be valuable to future readers.  Perhaps as a lesson to search more thoroughly when reading the Standard.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I certainly urge you not to delete a question, even if trivial. How else is the next person asking a similar question to find the answer otherwise ? (not everybody has a Standard at hand or manages to navigate it...)

Comment: In C++11, you could also use `template<class Iter, class Field = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>` so that you can write just `foo(&a, &a + 1)` and let argument deduction play its role.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is in the paragraph before the one you quote:

> 4/ For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

(Note: I'm quoting C++11 as I don't have C++03 to hand. I'm fairly sure nothing has changed.)

So yes, `&na + 1` is a valid past-the-end pointer.

Comment: And yes, the quote is identical in C++03.

Comment: And C++98, and N3797.