# Accessing value(which is an address) stored in an address pointed by pointer variable returns garbage value?

Tags: c++, pointers

When I tried to access the value(which is an address) stored in the address pointed by the pointer variable, a garbage value is returned. I have posted the code and the output below.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int *a, b=10, *c;
    a = &b;
    c = &b+1;

    cout << "Address of A : " << &a << endl;
    cout << "Value of A : " << a << endl;
    cout << "Value pointed by A : " << *a << endl;
    cout << "Address of B : " << &b << endl;
    cout << "Value of B : " << b << endl;
    cout << "Value of C : " << c << endl;
    cout << "Value pointed by C : " << *c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of A : 0x7fff3e608d20
Value of A : 0x7fff3e608d1c
Value pointed by A : 10
Address of B : 0x7fff3e608d1c
Value of B : 10
Value of C : 0x7fff3e608d20
Value pointed by C : 1046514972
```

In the above program, the address pointed by `c` is the address of `a` yet `*c` gives garbage value `1046514972` instead of `0x7fff3e608d1c`.

I know, I can access the value of A in some other way but my question is why couldn't I access it in this way. Is this an expected behaviour? If yes, can somebody please explain? Thank you.

Comment: How is `&b+1` the same as `a`? Any behavior is expected here.

Comment: (and you shouldn't be expecting a hex string (an address) when printing `*c`, a *value*).

Comment: Most likely `1046514972` is the overflowed result of `0x7fff3e608d1c`

Comment: @LogicStuff (&b+1) is the address of a. So, doing *(&b+1) should give the value at the address of a, i guess.

Comment: `&b +1` is the address of `b` **incremented by one** so it's different from the address of `b`. You wrote `a = &b` so `a` contains the address of `b`. How the address `&b+1` which is not the address of `b` and is unrelated to `a` could be the address of `a`? Where did you learn that from?

Comment: From the output produced by the compiler, it is way clear that the address of a and the value of &b+1 are same. The memory allocated for a and b by the compiler is contiguous, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = &b+1;
//...
*c
```

That's undefined behaviour. Forming a pointer to the location after a variable is valid, but performing indirection through it is not<sup>1</sup>. Even though some object happens to be there, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants.

As to why `1046514972` is printed, that's `0x3e608d1c` in hex. It's just the bytes of the 64 bit pointer reinterpreted as a 32 bit integer. You just happen to get something which kind of makes sense, but since this is undefined behaviour, it's semantically garbage.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically it's the l-to-rvalue conversion which is undefined, but you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: A single element is considered an array of size one for the purposes of pointer arithmetic

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you have any standards quotes for that? Regardless of whether the pointer arithmetic is valid, it's still undefined behaviour due to the l-to-rvalue conversion on the pointee.

Comment: It is [expr.add]/4 in the C++14 standard: For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

Comment: `&b + 1` is valid, but dereferencing the result is not. So, for example, you could write `for (int* ip = &b; ip != &b + 1; ++ip) std::out << *ip << '\n';`.

Comment: Also see [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#footnote-85) from the newest draft.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! Is that better?

Comment: @TartanLlama Kinda.  I removed the down vote but I fail to see where l-to-rvalue conversion comes in and why it is undefined behavior.  citing [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411102/treating-a-single-object-like-an-array-with-one-element-taking-one-past-end-poi), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405555/string-s-s1-legal-ub), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505851/is-the-one-past-the-end-pointer-of-a-non-array-type-a-valid-concept-in-c), and [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441390/iterating-over-a-single-lvalue)

Comment: @NathanOliver See [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232).

Comment: I still don't see it.  There is no l-value to r-value conversion going on here that I can see.  The only UB I see is the the use of the value stored in the one past the end pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Using the value *is* the l-to-rvalue conversion.